failed to upgrade solana program
I always close and redeploy but Its annoying ... so i need to upgrade instead .
solana program upgrade target/deploy/program-keypair.json new_program.json owner.json -u "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=7e466"
Error: Upgrading program failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument [3 log messages]
how to fix it or to find the log messages.
this is how I deploy .
solana program deploy target/deploy/program.so -u "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=7e466" --program-id new_program.json
I tried with this simple program .
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    msg,
};

// declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
    // log a message to the blockchain
    msg!("Hello, world!");
    // msg!("Hello, world!");
    Ok(())
}

[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "hello_world"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.2"


still nothing .

There might be an issue with the new version of your program, ie. it's using a syscall unsupported by mainnet. The CLI unfortunately isn't properly reporting deployment errors at the moment, but that will be fixed soon.

@JonC thanks for responding, I tried with a simple hello world program but same .

@JonC here its .
https://imgur.com/a/HTkLnbz

seems like i'm doing something wrong ... since target/deploy/program-keypair.json file isn't modified since its generated for the first time

target/deploy/program-keypair.json is just a keypair you can use to deploy -- you'll want to actually deploy target/deploy/program.so

@JonC I actually thought about doing it like that just for testing (deploying again and use the buffer account to do the upgrade), but it doesn't make sense .
I thought its all in the upgrade command.(write-buffer + upgrade)

Sometime I forgot check my balance address authority, so I don't have enough SOL balance to pay fee. LOL

This could help someone like me.
The issue in my case was I'm using the target/deploy/program-keypair.json key-pair as the buffer account which is obviously wrong , instead you'll need to write a new buffer account (deploy the program to a buffer account) and then use the buffer Pubkey to do the upgrade.
so after deploying and you're willing to upgrade , you'll need to do this.

solana program write-buffer path/to/program.so. (you'll get a buffer pubkey).

solana program upgrade BUFFER_PUBKEY PROGRAM_PUBKEY.


